# Algorithmic sorting solution to brain teaser/puzzle

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

You may have seen ordering brain teasers before:

> During the latest round of the BrainBashers triathlon, Keith was
> fourth. Adrian is not the oldest, but is older than Duncan, who was
> not second. The child who was next in age to the youngest, finished
> second. The child who finished in third place is older than the child
> who finished first. Billy is younger than the child who finished in
> third place. Can you determine who finished where and place the
> children in order of age? [[Source]](http://www.brainbashers.com/showpuzzles.asp?formpost=Y&field=ctop10a&page=1&puzzletext=A)

I'm looking for an algorithmic approach to solve what seems to be a very similar problem.

I have a set of objects which I would like to sort based on rules that related the objects to each other. For a given set of rules, there may be more than one solution. And in a valid solution, all the rules are met. It is also possible for a set of rules to have no valid solutions.

**Example:**

Objects: `A, B, C, D, E, and F`

Rules:

- C > A
- C < D
- F < C
- A > F
- E > F
- D > E

One possible solution:

```
 F A C E D B
```

Note that object B was not related to any of the other objects so it doesn't matter where it appears in the sequence.

Surely this has been done before. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I will ultimately be performing this sorting in Java.

***Related Question:***
[`Java partially ordered Collection<E>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362819/java-partially-ordered-collectione)

Comment: There are a lot of CSP (Constraint Satisfaction Problem) solver out there. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem

Comment: I solved the puzzle you quoted while reading the question.. and now you have enough answers.. maybe I am too slow. Or the others didn't solve the puzzle! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use the rules to build up a [*directed graph*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29), and then perform a [*topological sort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort).

**Note:** I have no idea whether this is the most efficient method, it's just the first thing I thought of.  However, this is *O(N)*, so you're not going to do much better from an asymptotic point-of-view!

Comment: This seems like the way to go. But... I'm going to let this question sit for a while and see what happens!

Answer (score 3):

It's not efficient but a simple brute force way is

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");
do {
    Collections.shuffle(names);
} while (!(
        names.indexOf("C") < names.indexOf("A") &&
                names.indexOf("C") > names.indexOf("D") &&
                names.indexOf("F") > names.indexOf("C") &&
                names.indexOf("A") < names.indexOf("F") &&
                names.indexOf("E") < names.indexOf("F") &&
                names.indexOf("D") < names.indexOf("E")));
System.out.println("A solution is " + names);
```

prints

```
A solution is [D, C, A, B, E, F]
```

Comment: Isn't this something like O(N.N!) average case?

Comment: I like it (even though I can't bring myself to use this in my application).

Answer (score 1):

[Edit, better explanation]
Use objects with no predecessors, then use objects with no predecessors but those already used, and so on.

You may look at all the predecessors of an object, then look if you find one with no predecessors and place it in first position. Then you look for objects having no other predecessors than the one already used. And so on...